# Add two strings in a list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I am trying to create a system that will take a multiline string with names as input and will output the lines as a 2d list with the first names and surnames joined. My issue is that both first names and surnames and just first names may be given as an input. This may be confusing so I have an example below.

This is in Python 3.6.

I have a list of first names:

```
Bob
Steve
Ted
Blake
Harry
Edric
Tommy
Bartholomew
```

and a list of surnames:

```
Fischer
Stinson
McCord
Bone
Harvey
```

Input

```
"""Bob Fischer Steve Ted Stinson Blake Harry McCord
Edric Bone Tommy Harvey Bartholomew"""
```

Output

```
[["Bob Fischer","Steve","Ted Stinson","Blake","Harry McCord"],
["Edric Bone","Tommy Harvey","Bartholomew"]]
```

I get really stuck on the differentiating between spaces between sets of names (`Steve Ted`) and the first and surnames.

Can anyone help with this? I'm really stuck...

Comment: What if firstnames and lastnames overlap? Are both firstnames and lastnames single words?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem They are guaranteed never to overlap.

Comment: Can a name or lastname contain a space in itself?

Comment: So, the first name is obligatory, and the surname can go missing? Check [this regex solution](http://ideone.com/49YPwv).

Comment: @Adirio No. All allowed inputs are ones that follow the examples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you want to post that as an answer feel free as it seems to fit what I trying to do. I'll test it on the full lists I have but it looks promising

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to match a first name that is optionally followed with whitespace(s)  and a last name.

You may create a single regex pattern from the name lists you have and use `re.findall` to find all non-overlapping occurrences:

```
import re
first = ['Bob','Steve','Ted','Blake','Harry','Edric','Tommy','Bartholomew']
surnames = ['Fischer','Stinson','McCord','Bone','Harvey']
r = r"\b(?:{})\b(?:\s+(?:{})\b)?".format("|".join(first),"|".join(surnames))
s = """Bob Fischer Steve Ted Stinson Blake Harry McCord
Edric Bone Tommy Harvey Bartholomew"""
print(re.findall(r, s))
# => ['Bob Fischer', 'Steve', 'Ted Stinson', 'Blake', 'Harry McCord', 'Edric Bone', 'Tommy Harvey', 'Bartholomew']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/jjPC5p)

The [regex that is generated with this code](https://regex101.com/r/sxcGVm/1):

```
\b(?:Bob|Steve|Ted|Blake|Harry|Edric|Tommy|Bartholomew)\b(?:\s+(?:Fischer|Stinson|McCord|Bone|Harvey)\b)?
```

Basically, `\b(?:...)\b(?:\s+(?:...)\b)?` matches a first name from the alternatives as a *whole word* (due to `\b` around the first `(?:...)` grouping construct) and then `(?:\s+(?:...)\b)?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences (due to `?` quantifier) of 1+ whitespaces (`\s+`) followed with any of the last names (again, as whole words due to the trailing `\b`).

Comment: Citing Jamie Zawinski: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Those people did not know how to use regex.

Comment: Is there a way of adapting this to include numbers as well in the first or surname?

Comment: After 6 months you will need to add some German names: "Otto von Bismarck" (which contains 3 words). Good luck redoing the regexp to capture the different cases and maintaining the code.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Not a problem: I will replace `\b` with `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` in the appropriate places. The firstnames and last names must be sorted by length in the descending order for that to work in that scenario. This is  all obvious and easy.

Comment: @ThisGuy: What do you need by *is there a way of adapting this to include numbers as well in the first or surname?*

Comment: I realised that I have some usernames in the list with numbers in the name and want to know if I can convert the regex to catch names with numbers.

Comment: If you have them in the list, they will become part of the regex pattern. You do not need to worry about that. Unless there are numbers in the names you will have in the input text that you will need to match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used (instead of surname and first name) a noun and the category they fall under.

```
A = [ 'Beaver' , 'Strawberry']
B = [ 'Animal' , 'Fruit']

input_string = 'Beaver Animal Strawberry Strawberry Fruit'
input_string = input_string.split(' ')

def combinestring( x_string ):
    compiling_string = []

    for i,x in enumerate(x_string):

        if (i+1) < len(x_string):
            if x in A and x_string[i+1] in B:
                compiling_string.append(x + ' ' + x_string[i+1])
            elif x in A:
                compiling_string.append(x)

        elif (i+1) == len(x_string) and x in A:
            compiling_string.append(x)

    return compiling_string



print combinestring(input_string)
#>>> ['Beaver Animal','Strawberry','Strawberry Fruit']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [21]: first_names
Out[21]: ['Bob', 'Steve', 'Ted', 'Blake', 'Harry', 'Edric', 'Tommy', 'Bartholomew']

In [22]: surnames
Out[22]: ['Fischer', 'Stinson', 'McCord', 'Bone', 'Harvey']

In [23]: inp = """Bob Fischer Steve Ted Stinson Blake Harry McCord
    ...: Edric Bone Tommy Harvey Bartholomew""".split()

In [24]: out = []
    ...: fullname = None
    ...: for name in inp:
    ...:     if name in first_names:
    ...:         if fullname:
    ...:             out.append(fullname)
    ...:         fullname = name
    ...:     elif name in surnames:
    ...:         fullname += ' ' + name
    ...: out.append(fullname)
    ...:

In [25]: out
Out[25]:
['Bob Fischer',
 'Steve',
 'Ted Stinson',
 'Blake',
 'Harry McCord',
 'Edric Bone',
 'Tommy Harvey',
 'Bartholomew']
```